# Problem. Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex, unit-test

Please help me fix my test.

```
 @isTest
public class TestProductTableApplication {
    @testSetup  static void setup() {
    ProductTable__c product = new ProductTable__c (Name = 'carrot', Price__c = 10, Amount__c = 1500 );
    INSERT product;
}
  @isTest static void getProducts (){
   ProductTable__c testproduct = ProductTableCmpController.getProducts();
   System.assertEquals(testproduct.Price__c, 10);
}  
}
```

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getProducts() from the type ProductTableCmpController

```
public class ProductTableCmpController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List < ProductTable__c > getProducts (String searchKeyWord) {
    String searchKey = '%'+ searchKeyWord + '%';
    List <ProductTable__c> returnList = new List <ProductTable__c> ();
    List <ProductTable__c> lstOfProducts = [select id, Name, Amount__c, Price__c, ProductType__c, ReleaseDate__c, Available__c, AddedDate__c from ProductTable__c where Name LIKE: searchKey ORDER BY AddedDate__c DESC];
    for (ProductTable__c acc: lstOfProducts) {
        returnList.add(acc);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SF Stack Exchange.

First you need to set your instantiation
 `ProductTable__c testproduct = ProductTableCmpController.getProducts();` in your test to a List. The method you are calling is a list, so the test method needs to also be a list.

Your method also receive a parameter of type string.

> public static List < ProductTable__c > getProducts (String
>   searchKeyWord)

So you need to pass also a string to your test method. 
Something like this:

`List<ProductTable__c> testproduct = ProductTableCmpController.getProducts(serachString);`

It is telling you that it doesn't exist because you don't have a method in that controller that don't accept parameters, which it is true. But you have the one accepting a string as parameter which it is the correct method you are using.

Something like this should work:

```
@isTest
   public class TestProductTableApplication {
    @testSetup  static void setup() {
    ProductTable__c product = new ProductTable__c (Name = 'carrot', 
    Price__c = 10, Amount__c = 1500 );
    INSERT product;
    }
    @isTest static void getProducts (){
    String searchString = 'Whatever';
    List<ProductTable__c> testproduct = ProductTableCmpController.getProducts(searchString);
    // put your asserts here
   }  
  }
```

**FOR DELETE:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteProductTable (List<Id> productIds) {
    List<ProductTable__c> productsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM 
ProductTable__c WHERE Id in :productIds];
    delete productsToDelete;       
}
```

The method **deleteProductTable** accepts a List of Ids **List productIds**

That means that you need to pass the exact data type to you test method in order to make it work.

So you can do something like this:

```
@isTest static void deleteProductTable (){
 List<Id> productTableIds = new List<Id>();

 // Lest just add two Ids to keep this simple.
 ProductTable__c pTableOne = new ProductTable__c();
 ProductTable__c pTableTwo = new ProductTable__c();

 // You need to add those mandatory fields before inserting a record
 // In this case we use the Name field as the only mandatory field
 // but you need to figurate out the ones you need for your 
 // ProductTable__c record
 pTableOne.Name = 'POne';
 insert pTableOne;

 pTableTwo.Name = 'PTwo';
 insert pTableTwo;

 // After inserting the records we have access to their Ids
 // Now we add the ids to our list
 productTableIds.add(pTableOne.Id);
 productTableIds.add(pTableOne.Id);

 // Now we can pass our list to the method as parameter

 List<ProductTable__c> testproduct = 
 ProductTableCmpController.deleteProductTable(productTableIds);
// put your asserts here
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: but what if the method accepts a parameter of type list?

Comment: Then you pass a list. Something like this: 
`public static List < Whatever > getProducts (List<Whatever> listOfWhatever)`

in your test you need to build a List and pass it to the test method. 
`@isTest static void getWhatever (){
List<Whatever> myList = new List<Whatever>()
// You can add single record to the list by using 
myList.add(whatever);
//Then pass the list to the test method
List<Whatever> testproduct = ProductTableCmpController.getProducts(myList);
 }`

Comment: Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @isTest
public class TestProductTableApplication {
        @testSetup  static void setup() {
        ProductTable__c product = new ProductTable__c (Name = 'carrot', Price__c = 10, Amount__c = 1500 );
        INSERT product;
    }
   @isTest static void deleteProductTable(){
        ProductTable__c product = new ProductTable__c(Name = 'Test');
        insert product;
       ProductTable__c testproduct = ProductTableCmpController.deleteProductTable(product.Id);
        Integer productsAfter = [select count() from ProductTable__c];
        System.assertEquals(1, productsAfter);
    }
}
```

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deleteProductTable(Id) from the type ProductTableCmpController

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void deleteProductTable (List<Id> productIds) {
        List<ProductTable__c> productsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM ProductTable__c WHERE Id in :productIds];
        delete productsToDelete;       
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE yuri. Can you call out what you chaged, and why? As it is while this may fix the issue, it doesn't really teach or explain why.

Comment: In my test, the method getProducts did not receive parameters, so it did not exist. We passed the text value into it and thanks to this the method worked.

Comment: But how to repeat this for a method deleteProductTable.

Comment: Check the DELETE section on the first answer.